# Jetty Websocket IdleTimeout

Tags: java, session, websocket, timeout, jetty

I've been working on annotated websockets lately, with the `Jetty API (9.4.5 release)` , and made a chat  with it.

However i got an issue, after 5 minutes (which i believe is the default timer), the session is closed (it is not due to an error).
The only solution I've found yet, is to notify my socket On closing event and reopen the connection in a new socket.

However i've read on stackOverflow, that by setting `IdleTimeOut` in the WebsocketPolicy, i could avoid the issue:

1. I've tried setting to `3600000` for instance, but the behavior does not change at all
2. I also tried to set it to `-1` but i get the following error: `IdleTimeout [-1] must be a greater than or equal to 0`

   ```
   private ServletContextHandler setupWebsocketContext() {
       ServletContextHandler websocketContext = new AmosContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS |  ServletContextHandler.SECURITY);

       WebSocketHandler socketCreator = new WebSocketHandler(){
           @Override
           public void  configure(WebSocketServletFactory factory){    
               factory.getPolicy().setIdleTimeout(-1);
               factory.getPolicy().setMaxTextMessageBufferSize(MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE);
               factory.getPolicy().setMaxBinaryMessageBufferSize(MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE);
               factory.getPolicy().setMaxTextMessageSize(MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE);
               factory.getPolicy().setMaxBinaryMessageSize(MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE);          
               factory.setCreator(new UpgradedSocketCreator());


           }

       };  
       ServletHolder sh = new ServletHolder(new WebsocketChatServlet());  
       websocketContext.addServlet(sh, "/*");  
       websocketContext.setContextPath("/Chat");
       websocketContext.setHandler(socketCreator);
       websocketContext.getSessionHandler().setMaxInactiveInterval(0);
       return websocketContext;
   }
   ```

I've also tried to change the policy directly in the `OnConnect` event, by using the call `session.getpolicy.setIdleTimeOut()`, but I haven't noticed any results.

Is this an expected behavior or am I missing something? Thanks for your help.

EDIT:

Log on the closure: 
Client Side:

```
2017-07-03T12:48:00.552 DEBUG   HttpClient@179313750-scheduler  Ignored idle endpoint SocketChannelEndPoint@2fb4b627{localhost/127.0.0.1:5080<->/127.0.0.1:53835,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=1/300000}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}->WebSocketClientConnection@e0198ece[ios=IOState@3ac0ec79[CLOSING,in,!out,close=CloseInfo[code=1000,reason=null],clean=false,closeSource=LOCAL],f=Flusher[queueSize=0,aggregateSize=0,failure=null],g=Generator[CLIENT,validating],p=Parser@65c4d838[ExtensionStack,s=START,c=0,len=187,f=null]]
```

Server side:

```
 2017-07-03T12:48:00.595    DEBUG   Idle pool thread    onClose WebSocketServerConnection@e0033d54[ios=IOState@10d40dca[CLOSED,!in,!out,finalClose=CloseInfo[code=1000,reason=null],clean=true,closeSource=REMOTE],f=Flusher[queueSize=0,aggregateSize=0,failure=null],g=Generator[SERVER,validating],p=Parser@317213f3[ExtensionStack,s=START,c=0,len=2,f=CLOSE[len=2,fin=true,rsv=...,masked=true]]]<-SocketChannelEndPoint@690dfbfb'{'/127.0.0.1:53835<->/127.0.0.1:5080,CLOSED,fill=-,flush=-,to=1/360000000}'{'io=0/0,kio=-1,kro=-1}->WebSocketServerConnection@e0033d54[ios=IOState@10d40dca[CLOSED,!in,!out,finalClose=CloseInfo[code=1000,reason=null],clean=true,closeSource=REMOTE],f=Flusher[queueSize=0,aggregateSize=0,failure=null],g=Generator[SERVER,validating],p=Parser@317213f3[ExtensionStack,s=START,c=0,len=2,f=CLOSE[len=2,fin=true,rsv=...,masked=true]]]
2017-07-03T12:48:00.595 DEBUG   Idle pool thread    org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Invocable$InvocableExecutor@4f13dee2 invoked org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$$Lambda$193/682154970@551e133a
2017-07-03T12:48:00.595 DEBUG   Idle pool thread    EatWhatYouKill@6ba355e4/org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer@7b1559f1/PRODUCING/0/1 produce exit
2017-07-03T12:48:00.595 DEBUG   Idle pool thread    ran EatWhatYouKill@6ba355e4/org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer@7b1559f1/PRODUCING/0/1
2017-07-03T12:48:00.595 DEBUG   Idle pool thread    run EatWhatYouKill@6ba355e4/org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer@7b1559f1/PRODUCING/0/1
2017-07-03T12:48:00.595 DEBUG   Idle pool thread    EatWhatYouKill@6ba355e4/org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer@7b1559f1/PRODUCING/0/1 run
2017-07-03T12:48:00.597 DEBUG   Idle pool thread    127.0.0.1 has disconnected ! 

2017-07-03T12:48:00.597 DEBUG   Idle pool thread    Disconnected:  127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1)  (statusCode= 1,000 , reason=null)
```

Comment: can you post your logs? if a socket is closed by the other side you usually get some kind of error. also keepalive settings might affect that

Comment: I will edit the comment to add the log on the client and server side.
However i haven't found any keepalive parameter in the policy.
Is it a thing in Jetty Websocket API ?

Comment: this answer may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44882256/jetty-websocket-idletimeout/50951002#50951002

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Annotated WebSockets have their own timeout settings in the annotation.

```
@WebSocket(maxIdleTime=30000)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Joakim, it works !
Can i also set maxIdleTime at -1 for an infinite keepalive timer ? 
It doesn't seem to work,  anyway i could just set an IdleTime long enough, so the issue is solved.

Comment: Be aware that ServerConnector(s) may also have an IdleTimeout setting which may overrule WebSocket Idle Timeout settings.

Comment: @GérardBinkhorst the WebSocket idle timeout overrides the idle timeout for the ServerConnector & Channel & EndPoint for this websocket connection.

Comment: My comment wasn't clearly formulated. Having a connector idle timeout of say 10s will idle timeout a websocket after 10s, even if the websocket idle timeout value is set larger.

Answer (score 4):

The annotation @WebSocket has option:

```
int maxIdleTime() default -2;
```

In fact it's not clear what does it mean.

If you check implementation, you can find:

```
if (anno.maxIdleTime() > 0)
{
this.policy.setIdleTimeout(anno.maxIdleTime());
}
```

method implementation:

```
/**
 * The time in ms (milliseconds) that a websocket may be idle before closing.
 * 
 * @param ms
 *            the timeout in milliseconds
 */
public void setIdleTimeout(long ms)
{
    assertGreaterThan("IdleTimeout",ms,0);
    this.idleTimeout = ms;
}
```

and finally:

```
/**
 * The time in ms (milliseconds) that a websocket may be idle before closing.
 * <p>
 * Default: 300000 (ms)
 */
private long idleTimeout = 300000;
```

Conclusion: negative value apply default behavior (300000 ms). You need to configure 'idleTimeout' according your business value.

PS: solved my case with:

```
@WebSocket(maxIdleTime = Integer.MAX_VALUE)
```

Comment: Super long idle timeouts, or infinite idle timeouts, are rarely a good idea on a production machine with many users.  (If this doesn't apply to you, then go ahead and set a super long idle timeout)

Comment: Mostly its right. In my case it was web cam video stream. Open / close connection is separate logic.