# Jetty WebSocket TimeOutException: Idle timeout expired?

Tags: websocket, timeout, jetty

I am on Jetty Websocket (jetty-all-9.4.5.v20170502-uber.jar) on the server side getting one time out :

```
**java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 300011/300000 ms**
Socket Closed: CloseReason[1001,Idle Timeout]
Socket Closed: CloseReason[1001,Idle Timeout]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout.checkIdleTimeout(IdleTimeout.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout$1.run(IdleTimeout.java:50)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)**
```

This is a unique event at the beginning and everything else works perfectly!

I tried to change this:

```
_context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
_context.setContextPath("/");
System.out.println(_context.getStopTimeout());
_context.setStopTimeout(0);
_server.setHandler(_context);
```

~ without success !

No idea.

Comment: this answer may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44882256/jetty-websocket-idletimeout/50951002#50951002

Answer (score 2):

> WARNING: [Don't use `jetty-all` for your project, its not meant to be used outside of the Jetty Quickstart Documentation.](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-users/msg06030.html)

Idle Timeout in WebSocket is controlled by the [WebSocketPolicy](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/9.4.11.v20180605/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/api/WebSocketPolicy.html).

The Idle Timeout can be specified on the WebSocket Container (eg: WebSocketClient or WebSocketServletFactory) or even on the individual connected WebSocket Sessions.

Your code example doesn't show anything to do with WebSocket, so I cannot provide you the specific information you need to configure your websocket behavior.

Comment: Thank you! In the `WebSocketListener.onWebSocketConnect()` I just have to set the idle timeout e.g. `session.setIdleTimeout(1000)`. The default timeout of 5 minutes (300000ms) seems reasonable though. Instead I'll configure the websocket client to perform ping every 1 minute.