# Unable to set a jetty websocket maxIdleTimeout above 60 seconds

Tags: java, session, websocket, timeout, jetty

Am trying to use jetty websockets, and wish to setup with a user configurable idle timeout setting for connected sessions. It seems everything tried results in a timeout at 60 seconds:

```
org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.CloseException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 60002/60000 ms
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.onReadTimeout(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:567)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection.onFillInterestedFailed(AbstractConnection.java:172)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.onFillInterestedFailed(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:540)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.failed(AbstractConnection.java:317)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.onFail(FillInterest.java:138)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.onFillableFail(SslConnection.java:579)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillInterestedFailed(SslConnection.java:407)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$2.failed(SslConnection.java:167)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.onFail(FillInterest.java:138)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractEndPoint.onIdleExpired(AbstractEndPoint.java:407)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout.checkIdleTimeout(IdleTimeout.java:171)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout.idleCheck(IdleTimeout.java:113)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
```

Using Jetty 9.4.26 and using @WebSocket annotated pojos for each ws session.

Setting a value in the annotation is not really workable as the idle timeout needs to be configurable at runtime. However even when set, it only makes a difference if set to something less than 60 seconds:

```
@WebSocket(maxIdleTime = 65000) \\Idle timeout expired: 60002/60000 ms
@WebSocket(maxIdleTime = 50000) \\Idle timeout expired: 50001/50000 ms
```

Exactly the same if I manually set the timeout on the session passed into the @OnWebSocketConnect method:

```
session.setIdleTimeout(65000); \\Idle timeout expired: 60001/60000 ms
session.setIdleTimeout(50000); \\Idle timeout expired: 50001/50000 ms
```

Am calling connect() on a WebSocketClient which I am instantiating as a singleton, and passing the annotated pojo into connect():

```
HttpClient jettyHttpClient = new HttpClient(getWebSocketSslContextFactory());
jettyHttpClient.start();
WebSocketClient wsClient = new WebSocketClient(jettyHttpClient);
wsClient.start();
```

However the above timeout behavior is still identical if using either of these:

```
wsClient.getPolicy().setIdleTimeout(65000);
wsClient.setMaxIdleTimeout(65000);
```

jettyHttpClient.setIdleTimeout(); seems to have no affect at all....

Adding a breakpoint into setIdleTimeout() of IdleTimeout is not making things much clearer, this breakpoint is hit 6 times on 4 different instances during a connection:

```
0       set in SocketChannelEndpoint (instance 1)   via  ClientSelectorManager.newEndPoint
300000  set in SocketChannelEndpoint (instance 2)   via  ServerConnector.newEndPoint
-1      set in SslConnection$DecyptedEndPoint (instance 1) via Constructor
-1      set in SslConnection$DecyptedEndPoint (instance 2) via setIdleTimeout
60000   set in SocketChannelEndpoint (instance 2)  via  WebSocketServerFactory.upgrade
65000   set in SocketChannelEndpoint (instance 1)  via  WebSocketUpgradeRequest.upgrade
```

Am basically lost as to what is going on internally. There are 5 ways of setting the timeout and nothing seems to work above 60 seconds.

Similar request to this thread, but didn't have enough rep to comment there, hence new thread.
[Jetty Websocket IdleTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44882256/jetty-websocket-idletimeout)

Comment: Upgrade your version of Jetty.  Version 9.4.26 is on the older side, and there's been many updates to the websocket impl since then.  In fact, I can see that we have testcases specifically for this scenario in the current release.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt Many thanks for the suggestion. Can you confirm if you mean moving to jetty 10+ or more recent 9.x versions? Currently restricted to java 8 by framework this code sits within, so Jetty 9 only unfortunately for the foreseeable.

Comment: Jetty 10 and Jetty 11 are currently in pre-release. Use the Jetty 9.4.x releases as they are the stable branches.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt Thank you, I will try again at a later date with a more recent version and report back.